# Criar array com string em php?

Tags: php

Tenho uma váriavel texto e queria criar um array com a mesma, é possível?
segue a váriavel:

```
$texto = "forma=3&banco=100&agencia=200&conta=300&cheque=404";
```

a saída que desejo seria está:

```
array(
'forma' => '3',
'banco' => '100',
'agencia' => '200',
'conta' => '300',
'cheque' => '404'
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há uma função PHP para isso, chama-se [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) e funciona assim:

```
$texto = "forma=3&banco=100&agencia=200&conta=300&cheque=404";
parse_str($texto, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Resultado:

```
array(5) { 
  ["forma"]=> string(1) "3" 
  ["banco"]=> string(3) "100" 
  ["agencia"]=> string(3) "200" 
  ["conta"]=> string(3) "300" 
  ["cheque"]=> string(3) "404" 
}
```

Comment: perfeito! exatamente o que estava precisando.